# EXPO Android - makeDirectoryAsync() error “could not be created”

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, filesystems, expo

We are getting Sentry reports from our Android customers who get errors during makeDirectoryAsync(). The error is:

```
  Error: Directory 'file:///data/user/0/companyName/cache/ExperienceData/%2540companyName%252FappName/content/' could not be created..
```

The issue seem only to be related to users with Huawei phones (SKD 24-27).

The error accrue during our initial setup of the cache and this is the code.

```
    const TEMP_DIR = FileSystem.cacheDirectory
    const DIR_PATH = `${TEMP_DIR}${folderName}/`

    return FileSystem.getInfoAsync(DIR_PATH).then(info => {
      if (!info.exists) {
        return FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(DIR_PATH, {
          intermediates: true,
        }).then(() => {
          [...]
        })
      }

      [...]
  })
```

Expo sdk => 30.0.0

related issues:

https://forums.expo.io/t/makedirectoryasync-error-could-not-be-created/11916

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1980

We have not detached our app from expo.

thankful for any help.

Holger